# close current browser tab in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

1. I have tried below pieces of code to close current browser tab but none are working.
2. In fact they behave in yii2 way and try to navigate to same Controller/Action.

   ```
   <a href='' onclick="window.close()" class="btn btn-danger">Click to Close</a>

   <a href='#' onclick="window.close()" class="btn btn-danger">Click to Close</a>
   ```

The View in which above code is written is a PHP page. any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.close();return false;" class="btn btn-danger">Click to Close</a>
```

**UPDATED**:

Note: there is browser-specific differences with the above. If you opened the window with Javascript (via window.open()) then you are allowed to close the window with javascript. Firefox disallows you from closing other windows.  Other browsers may vary.

Comment: Thanks for reply and Nope :( . I have already tried that option. return false; makes no sense here as line after close(); shall never be executed, it is unreachable.

Comment: Seems you cannot do that until you have used window.open to open the tab.